# move root with rsync -aHA but sudo not work. How to fix?

Tags: linux, rsync, file-transfer

I ran `rsync -aHA --delete --devices -S -xv /media/tmp/oldroot/ /media/newroot/`. 
After I reboot, I can login. But I cannot use sudo and passwd.

How to fix this?

```
$ sudo ls
sudo: must be setuid root

$ passwd
Changing password for galaxy.
(current) UNIX password: 
passwd: Authentication failure
passwd: password unchanged
```

Comment: also `$ chromium
Failed to move to new PID namespace: Operation not permitted
`

Comment: Well, I just find I mount the new disk with `nosuid`. That is the reason. Maybe I should keep this question for those just made a mistake like me.

Comment: Go ahead add that comment as an answer. It lets us know that you have answered the question. And hey, you might just get upmodded ;)

Comment: I tried and found I cannot self-answer within 8 hours ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just find I mount the new disk with nosuid. That is the reason.